# Single instance Prisma client autocomplete not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, prisma, prisma2

I have a single instance prisma but it's not auto-completing any queries.

```js
const { PrismaClient } = require("@prisma/client");
let prisma;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  prisma = new PrismaClient();
  prisma.$connect();
} else {
  if (!global.__db) {
    global.__db = new PrismaClient();
    global.__db.$connect();
  }
  prisma = global.__db;
}
module.exports = prisma;
```

How can I get autocomplete intellisense ‍♂️?

Answer (score 7):

Worked for me to generate the schemas for the prisma-client

You should have defined in your `schema.prisma` the generator:

```
// datasource here

generator client {
    provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

// your models here
```

Then run:

```
npx prisma generate
```

This reads your schema definition and generates a version of `PrismaClient` with all the intellisense related to your models. This command must be executed every time you update your models definition.

The process is described [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/getting-started/setup-prisma/start-from-scratch/relational-databases/install-prisma-client-typescript-postgres).

Answer (score 6):

I was using VSCode and intellisense for prisma was not working either, even after generating the schema. Restarting VSCode solved it for me. Just reopening the script might solve it too.

Answer (score 1):

*./prisma/prisma-client-js.js*

```
const { PrismaClient } = require("@prisma/client");

class Db extends PrismaClient {
    static instance;
    constructor(){
        if(!Db.instance){
            Db.instance = new PrismaClient()
        }
        return Db.instance;
    }
}

module.exports = Db;
```

*index.js*

```
const Db = require('./prisma/prisma-client-js')
const dn = new Db();
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using Javascript. The way I was able to get Intellisense autocomplete is by using Typescript and defining the `prisma` variable as follow: `let prisma: PrismaClient;` if I remember correctly.

I think the Prisma extension for VSCode also includes some Intellisense autocomplete if I am correct.

Comment: I have that extension but not working as expected :')

Comment: @Robbi did you try using type definitions?